# How to bind data correctly to a ListBox so it would update [C#/WPF/MVVM]

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm seriously stuck with a trouble updating the bound data in WPF.
Basically, i've got some data in my app, which doesn't update when properties change and i can't fix it.

In my app i'm trying to use the MVVM pattern, so there is a Model with properties X, Y:

```
public class Сross : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            x = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

...there is a ViewModel, which contains an ObservableCollection of Crosses:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    Crosses = new ObservableCollection<Cross>()
    {
        new Cross ()
        {
            X = 300,
            Y = 200
        },
        new Cross ()
        {
            X = 400,
            Y = 300
        }
    };

    private ObservableCollection<Cross> crosses;
    public ObservableCollection<Cross> Crosses
    {
        get
        {
            return crosses;
        }
        set
        {
            crosses = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Crosses");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

...and there is a View, where there is a ListBox, databound to this ObservableCollection of Crosses.

```
<Page x:Class="CharMaker.App.MainPageView">
    <Page.DataContext>
         <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    ....

    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="#01FFFFFF" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
             <Binding Path="Crosses" Mode="TwoWay" />
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
             </Style>
         </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Page>
```

This code works so that when you move the Cross item (which has a DataTemplate based on Thumb control) in a ListBox field, it's Canvas.Left(or Top) is changing and it updates the X and Y properties of a Cross item, and the other way around.

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Cross}">
                            <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"
                           IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Canvas Margin="0">
                                            <Line X1="-5" X2="5" Y1="-5" Y2="5"  Stroke="#FF2E61AB" StrokeThickness="1.5" 
                                             x:Name="FirstLine" />

                                            <Line X1="-5" X2="5" Y1="5" Y2="-5"  Stroke="#FF2E61AB" StrokeThickness="1.5" 
                                             x:Name="SecondLine" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="FirstLine" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="SecondLine" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that after listbox is loaded (and Crosses appear on screen in the appropriate positions), they don't change the X and Y properies in the ViewModel as i move them. And if i change X and Y in ObservableCollection Crosses, they don't move on screen. 
It's worth mentioning, that i did a ListBox with TextBoxes for testing, which is also bound to X, Y properties of Crosses collection:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Crosses}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Cross}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

and the funny thing is that in this ListBox the Data Binding works just fine!
Values are changing in TextBoxes when i move crosses, and crosses move to positions when the value in TextBox is changed.

But in the very same time (if i pause the app) i see that the values in Observable Collection Crosses in ViewModel are same as they were when it was loaded first time.

Please, help me figure out, what the problem is!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the debug view show you when X,Y are changed? Is there any binding error found in the view?

Comment: What's your DataTemplate for the Cross look like?

Comment: @JeongKim Debug view shows, that even after moving crosses, X and Y are still the values loaded during initialization. But on the screen i see, that they were moved, and the TextBox with Coordinates shows the actual value.

Comment: @Peter i added DataTemplate in the description

Comment: @Lark3D Strangely it works fine here(moving the Cross on the main windows reflect back to Cross items in the collection and vice versa). The `Thumb_DragDelta` is simple as : var t = sender as Thumb;
            if (t != null)
            {
                var c = t.DataContext as Cross;
                if (c != null)
                {
                    c.X += e.HorizontalChange;
                    c.Y += e.VerticalChange;
                }

Comment: @Peter Yes, Thumb_DragDelta is implemented pretty much as you thought. I've been debugging it for some more time and discovered, that the cross from DataContext (var c = t.DataContext as Cross) has correct values , so c.X and c.Y are updated correctly. But this var c=t.DataContext is somehow disconnected with the original Cross in ObservableCollection Crosses in the ViewModel. It's like the View created a copy of each cross in Crosses during initialization and then works with them, not touching the objects in Crosses.

Comment: @Lark3D. From your description, seems like the problem is out-of-sync DataContext. Perhaps hooking up 'Page.DataContextChanged' event and debugging there might help.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of hours debugging this, it seems, i found the problem.

I had a Page with DataContext set to MainViewModel, and this Page was a child of MainWindow, which had also DataContext property set to MainViewModel. 
I didn't realize, that both Page and MainWindow created a MainViewModel instance of their own. 
So i had two instances and while one was working and updating as it should, another was just confusing me.

Stupid mistake, i know.
Thanks anyway for trying to help.